# Map existing folder in default document library with teams channel in MSTeams when creating teams from existing SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites, microsoft-teams

I want to create a teams from one of the existing SharePoint team site.

I know how to achieve this but I am concern about the existing Folders/files that are present in SharePoint default document library. I want to map this existing folder/Files with the teams channel. (As per my understanding whenever we create a new channel in teams, it created one folder in SharePoint's default document library. I want exactly reverse procedure i.e. channels from existing folder.)

e.g Suppose there is one folder name `Digital Initiatives` that contains files. I want a channel name `Digital Initiatives` by default to be created when I create teams from SharePoint Site.

I am not sure it it is possible or not.

If it is possible then can anyone please guideme on how to achieve this.

And if not possible then any workaround id someone has alredy implemented.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to create a channel from existing folder. It's by design.

As a workaround, you could add a tab in the channel from a custom document library in SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an existing folder under the default "Documents" (Shared Documents) document library and you add a new channel with the same name, then the new channel will be linked to the existing folder automatically:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dJj9XTTN-iA